# Hadoop: Iterative MapReduce Performance

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, iteration

Is it correct to say that the parallel computation with iterative MapReduce can be justified mainly when the training data size is too large for the non-parallel computation for the same logic?

I am aware that the there is overhead for starting MapReduce jobs.
This can be critical for overall execution time when a large number of iterations is required.

I can imagine that the sequential computation is faster than the parallel computation with iterative MapReduce as long as the memory allows to hold a data set in many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No parallel processing system makes much sense if a single machine does the job, most of the time. The complexity associated with most parallelization tasks is significant and requires a good reason to make use of it.

Even when it's obvious that a task can't be resolved without parallel processing in acceptable time, parallel execution frameworks come in different flavours: from the more low-level, science-oriented tools like [PVM or MPI](http://cobweb.ecn.purdue.edu/~pplinux/PPHOWTO/pphowto-3.html#ss3.5) to high-level, specialized (e.g. map/reduce) frameworks like Hadoop.

Among the parameters you should consider are start time and scalability (how close to linear does the system scale). Hadoop will not be a good choice if you need answers quickly, but might be a good choice if you can fit your process into a map-reduce frame.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to project HaLoop ( http://code.google.com/p/haloop ) which addresses exactly this problem.

Comment: @anuj There is really no reason for the bold editing you seem to do in various edits. The link is fine, but just give the projects its right capitalized spelling and you're good to go.